# Binding Directory to treeview in C# with visual studios

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Does anyone know how to bind a directory to a treeview in C# or know of a simple tutorial to follow along with? Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Something like this:

```
    public void BindDirectoryToTreeView(string directoryPathToBind)
    {
        TreeNode rootNode = new TreeNode();
        treeView1.Nodes.Add(rootNode);
        RecurseFolders(directoryPathToBind, rootNode);
    }

    public void RecurseFolders(string path, TreeNode node)
    {
        var dir = new DirectoryInfo(path);
        node.Text = dir.Name;

        try
        {
            foreach (var subdir in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                var childnode = new TreeNode();
                node.Nodes.Add(childnode);

                RecurseFolders(subdir.FullName, childnode);
            }
        }
        catch (UnauthorizedAccessException ex)
        {
            // TODO:  write some handler to log and/or deal with 
            // unauthorized exception cases
        }

        foreach (var fi in dir.GetFiles().OrderBy(c=>c.Name))
        {
            var fileNode = new TreeNode(fi.Name);
            node.Nodes.Add(fileNode);
        }
    }
```

You would invoke the code by calling `BindDirectoryToTreeView("c:\");` for instance.  Note that you should have a treeview named treeView1 on the form that has this code.

Comment: Where should I call the BindDirectorytoTreeView from to display the directory hierarchy?

Comment: If you want this to bind immediately on form creation, then put it in the constructor of the form.  Otherwise you can bind it to a button press, etc.  I left the method open so that you can call it from any form event.

Comment: Thanks. I just tried this and works good, although it doesn't pull every folder off my drive, i will play around with it and see if I can figure it out. Thanks again.

Comment: It seems like this just some hidden files along with the recycle bin. I was hoping to get inetpub folder structure, and other folders with the file included. 

Do I need another recursive function for this?

Comment: Given the recursive nature of this, if i started with "c:" wouldn't this iterate through every single folder on my hard disk?

Answer (score 0):

You can use simple recursion .Not sure what exactly you want to display in TreeView but the following approach can work

public static void LoadDir(TreeNode t,DirectoryInfo d) {

TreeNode tn= new TreeNode(d.name);

t.ChildNodes.Add(tn);

foreach(DirectoryInfo dn in d.GetDirectories())

LoadDir(tn,dn);
}

You can Invoke it as

TreeNode tn=new TreeNode("Root");

TreeView1.Nodes.Add(tn);

LoadDir(tn,new DirectoryInfo(@"C:\Oracle");

Comment: I am displaying it in a checkable treeview so when the end users selects particular files or folders I will replicate them over to a different location in a Boolean format. Would you suggest another way?