# Need something like "Solution Explorer" (Visual Studio)

Tags: c#

I would like to display a directory.
It should be as such as the Solution Explorer in Visual Studio looks like. (Treeview or something like that)

So that I (as an User) can also move files for example, dragging file A to Folder B and so on..

Hope u guys can help me..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3000899/binding-directory-to-treeview-in-c-with-visual-studios

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2263013/winforms-treeview-recursive-directory-listing

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6840629/how-to-get-client-file-system-directories-in-treeview-asp-net-c

Comment: showing is no problem, but how to enable "moving" or "deleting" files!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/542378/embedding-a-file-explorer-instance-in-a-winforms-app-form

Comment: only the last link (the answer of the question) helped me.. And my English also sucks, thats the reason, why I didn't search on stackoverflow before..

Comment: try some jquery treeview http://www.programmingsolution.net/useful-js/jquery-treeview.php

Comment: thx 4 answer, but I'm not creating a Website

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Deleting, an item in the tree view, you gotta write logic by yourself. First hook an generic popup menu for each treeview items. Then rightclick display it. Upon selection of deletion, take that item delete it and update the view.